# Kuka iiwa LBR locks up while waiting

Tags: kuka

I'm working with a Kuka iiwa LBR 14 R820 arm, doing research stuff at a university. I'm writing code in their Sunrise application and pushing Java programs to the Kuka controller box, where I run them on the "smartPad" pendant and observe the results. That all works.

My problem is that if I sit thinking for a bit (between 2 and 30 minutes?), the arm will make a loud click (brakes engaging?), and after that it will not move until I reboot the controller box. Running any application will either throw a Java exception or finish happily without actually moving. Even manual movements in their T1 safety mode won't happen. Nothing fixes it aside from rebooting. Which is very tiresome when it happens for the dozenth time in a day and very embarrassing if it happens during a demo.

It seems to take a random amount of time since last use (in that 2 to 30 minutes range). The arm is *always* stationary when it happens -- it's never stopped mid-movement. It seems to happen whether an application is actively running (but not moving) or it is running nothing. There is no external load on the arm, just gravity of the arm itself, so I don't think it is overloaded and I presume not overheated.

Is there some trigger that I can avoid?

Is there a command to unstick it?

Is there a parking mode? I had thought that leaving it in position hold helped, but no. I had thought that canceling the last motion helped, but no.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, RaveTheTadpole. Could be a faulty E-stop, could be some kind of timeout or heartbeat failure, could be something else that triggers a fault; [this documentation I found](https://www.oir.caltech.edu/twiki_oir/pub/Palomar/ZTF/KUKARoboticArmMaterial/Spez_LBR_iiwa_en.pdf) (warning: Direct PDF download) seems to state (Page 46) that faults cause the drives to disable and the brakes to set, which seems to be what you're experiencing. Unfortunately, probably your best bet is to reach out to Kuka directly and request troubleshooting support from them to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer.

You need to run the brake tests after system startup. There is a sample brake testing app in the Kuka software distribution, and that will suffice. Or you can write your own in Java.

Without running the brake test, the safety system will eventually decide to stop you from continuing. At that point, only the brake test app (or others that override the safeties) can run.

Unfortunately this does not fix all of the reasons the arm locks, but it does reduce the frequency. Further answers are welcome to address other sources of this symptom.